# Cannot install elm-lang/html 1.0.0

Tags: elm

I'm new in ELM, and i want to execute this code :

```
import Html exposing (..)

main = 
    text "hola yassine"
```

using elm platfrom 0.16.

Now, when i call http://localhost:8000/test.elm i have this error :

```
I cannot find module 'Html'.

Module 'Main' is trying to import it.

Potential problems could be:
  * Misspelled the module name
  * Need to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package
```

and when i execute the `elm package install elm-lang/html 1.0.0`to import it, i have this problem that depend on path :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrMMO.png)

Someone can help me please ?
thanks a lot.

Comment: I think if you are on 0.16 the path is still `evancz/html`

Comment: Any reason you are using Elm 0.16? You will find it harder learning using 0.16 than more recent versions.

Comment: it's our teacher who told us that we have to use 0.16

Comment: Why do teachers keep teaching outdated versions of programming languages?! A real mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're using Elm 0.16. `elm-lang/html` was written from scratch [for Elm 0.17](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/latest), which significantly changed basic language features (abolishing signals most notably). You could try using `evancz/elm-html` 4.0.2 (the last version to support Elm 0.16) or you could upgrade to Elm 0.18 (as of November 2016, the latest version).